# how to draw curved text in html canvas pie slices

Tags: html5-canvas

I am trying to curve the text in slices of pie in HTML5 canvas. I got some examples but all of them curve the text around the circle but I want to curve the text within the slice.

This is how my canvas looks like:

[image: see the following image]

Comment: how is "around the circle" different from "within the slice"? your circle will have a radius somewhere between the inner and outer radii of the slices, and be invisible. I'd suggest show the attempted solution from the examples you mention, and we can help adjusting that instead of writing all from scratch.

Comment: I would use SVG instead of canvas and everything would be easier. In SVG you can easily draw a text on a path, and you get a scalable image.